# How to parse and export line by line with python and pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I´m trying to parse a bible online, to scrape all books (book with Title, Chapters and Verses), and then exporta all using pandas.

But I´m too newer and just can export all text in one row and colum.

Here is the website: https://www.bibliaonline.com.br/ara/mt/1 (This is the url im trying)

Here is the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import time
from XanXSS.lib.settings import prettify

#Usando agent bypassing block-url browser

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

# Link para extrair os dados
def getdata(url): 
    r = requests.get(url) 
    return r.text 

url = getdata(f"https://www.bibliaonline.com.br/ara/mt/1") 
soup = BeautifulSoup(url, 'html.parser')


resultado = soup.find_all('div', class_="verseByVerse css-188hggs")
for resultado in resultado:
    espaco = soup.find('span', class_="bv")
    numero = soup.find_all('span', class_="v")
    verso = soup.find_all('span', class_="t")
    print(resultado.get_text())

#Armazena a informação no dataform do pandas
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[resultado.text]], columns=['Biblia'], index=['Mateus'])


# Adiciona um tempo de delay, entre cada requisição evitando inundar o site com requisições.
time.sleep(1)

#Exporta os dados para um arquivo CSV
df.to_csv('bibliatetelestai.csv', index=True)
```

I´m getting this result:

```
A genealogia de Jesus Cristo1 Livro da genealogia de Jesus Cristo, filho de Davi, filho de Abraão. 2 Abraão gerou a Isaque; Isaque, a Jacó; Jacó, a Judá e a seus irmãos; 3 Judá gerou de Tamar a Perez e a Zera; Perez gerou a Esrom; Esrom, a Arão; 4 Arão gerou a Aminadabe; Aminadabe, a Naassom; Naassom, a Salmom; 5 Salmom gerou de Raabe a Boaz; este, de Rute, gerou a Obede; e Obede, a Jessé; 6 Jessé gerou ao rei Davi; e o rei Davi, a Salomão, da que fora mulher de Urias; 7 Salomão gerou a Roboão; Roboão, a Abias; Abias, a Asa; 8 Asa gerou a Josafá; Josafá, a Jorão; Jorão, a Uzias; 9 Uzias gerou a Jotão; Jotão, a Acaz; Acaz, a Ezequias; 10 Ezequias gerou a Manassés; Manassés, a Amom; Amom, a Josias; 11 Josias gerou a Jeconias e a seus irmãos, no tempo do exílio na Babilônia. 12 Depois do exílio na Babilônia, Jeconias gerou a Salatiel; e Salatiel, a Zorobabel; 13 Zorobabel gerou a Abiúde; Abiúde, a Eliaquim; Eliaquim, a Azor; 14 Azor gerou a Sadoque; Sadoque, a Aquim; Aquim, a Eliúde; 15 Eliúde gerou a Eleazar; Eleazar, a Matã; Matã, a Jacó. 16 E Jacó gerou a José, marido de Maria, da qual nasceu Jesus, que se chama o Cristo. 17 De sorte que todas as gerações, desde Abraão até Davi, são catorze; desde Davi até ao exílio na Babilônia, catorze; e desde o exílio na Babilônia até Cristo, catorze. O nascimento de Jesus Cristo18 Ora, o nascimento de Jesus Cristo foi assim: estando Maria, sua mãe, desposada com José, sem que tivessem antes coabitado, achou-se grávida pelo Espírito Santo. 19 Mas José, seu esposo, sendo justo e não a querendo infamar, resolveu deixá-la secretamente. 20 Enquanto ponderava nestas coisas, eis que lhe apareceu, em sonho, um anjo do Senhor, dizendo: José, filho de Davi, não temas receber Maria, tua mulher, porque o que nela foi gerado é do Espírito Santo. 21 Ela dará à luz um filho e lhe porás o nome de Jesus, porque ele salvará o seu povo dos pecados deles. 22 Ora, tudo isto aconteceu para que se cumprisse o que fora dito pelo Senhor por intermédio do profeta: 23 Eis que a virgem conceberá e dará à luz um filho, e ele será chamado pelo nome de Emanuel (que quer dizer: Deus conosco). 24 Despertado José do sono, fez como lhe ordenara o anjo do Senhor e recebeu sua mulher. 25 Contudo, não a conheceu, enquanto ela não deu à luz um filho, a quem pôs o nome de Jesus.
```

How can I export the print, line by line, like this:

```
A genealogia de Jesus Cristo (Title of verse)

1 Livro da genealogia de Jesus Cristo, filho de Davi, filho de Abraão.
2 Abraão gerou a Isaque; Isaque, a Jacó; Jacó, a Judá e a seus irmãos;
3 Judá gerou de Tamar a Perez e a Zera; Perez gerou a Esrom; Esrom, a Arão; 
etc...
```

and export this one line per row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSV is not predestined for such an output with headlines, but to output the verses line by line you can extract them in exactly this way and store them

###### Example

```
...
soup = BeautifulSoup(url, 'html.parser')
versos = soup.select('div.verseByVerse p span.t')

data = []

for e in versos:
    data.append({
        'espaco': e.find_previous('div').get_text(strip=True),
        'numero': e.find_previous('span').get_text(strip=True),
        'verso': e.get_text(strip=True)
    })
#Armazena a informação no dataform do pandas
pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```

| espaco | numero | verso |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A genealogia de Jesus Cristo | 1 | Livro da genealogia de Jesus Cristo, filho de Davi, filho de Abraão. |
| A genealogia de Jesus Cristo | 2 | Abraão gerou a Isaque; Isaque, a Jacó; Jacó, a Judá e a seus irmãos; |
| A genealogia de Jesus Cristo | 3 | Judá gerou de Tamar a Perez e a Zera; Perez gerou a Esrom; Esrom, a Arão; |
| A genealogia de Jesus Cristo | 4 | Arão gerou a Aminadabe; Aminadabe, a Naassom; Naassom, a Salmom; |